# Typing indicator in Microsoft Teams through Graph API - chatMessageType 'typing'?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Currently using the graph API to show messages from a chat outside of microsoft teams.

I am looking for a way to display a typing indicator in my app. However, **I need to know when a user is typing in an ms teams chat** through the Graph API and can not find anything in the docs about this other than this mention of a ['typing' chatMessageType for messageType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

I don't know what this 'typing' type is or when it comes about. I am subscribed to messages in a chat but they all come through as 'message' when they're sent or **after** they're edited (editing the message/typing in the chat box does not trigger any events)

(I am aware of the bot framework but would rather not use it at this time)

Thanks

Comment: It seems that currently there is no Graph API to know that a user is typing a message in a chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as answer for more visibility.

Currently Graph API do not process Typing indicators. So it is not possible to know when a user is typing in an MS Teams chat through the Graph API.

You can raise it on [Microsoft Uservoice](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).